# OpenMP slow reduction

Tags: c++, openmp

I write simple C++ code that compute array reduction sum, but with OpenMP reduction program works slowly. There are two variants of program: one is simplest sum, another - sum of complex math function. In code complex variant is commented.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

#define N 100000000
#define NUM_THREADS 4

int main() {

  int *arr = new int[N];

  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    arr[i] = i;
  }

  omp_set_num_threads(NUM_THREADS);
  cout << NUM_THREADS << endl;

  clock_t start = clock();
  int sum = 0;
  #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:sum)
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    // sum += sqrt(sqrt(arr[i] * arr[i])); // complex variant
    sum += arr[i]; // simple variant
  }

  double diff = ( clock() - start ) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
  cout << "Time " << diff << "s" << endl;

  cout << sum << endl;

  delete[] arr;

  return 0;
}
```

I compile it by ICPC and GCC:

```
icpc reduction.cpp -openmp -o reduction -O3
g++ reduction.cpp -fopenmp -o reduction -O3
```

Processor: Intel Core 2 Duo T5850, OS: Ubuntu 10.10

There are execution time of simple and complex variants, compiled with and without OpenMP.

*Simple* variant "sum += arr[i];":

```
icpc
0.1s without OpenMP
0.18s with OpenMP

g++
0.11c without OpenMP
0.17c with OpenMP
```

*Complex* variant "sum += sqrt(sqrt(arr[i] * arr[i]));":

```
icpc
2,92s without OpenMP
3,37s with OpenMP

g++ 
47,97s without OpenMP
48,2s with OpenMP
```

In system monitor I see that 2 cores works in program with OpenMP and 1 core works in program without OpenMP. I'll try several numbers of threads in OpenMP and dont have speedup. I don't understand why reduction is slow.

Comment: For the simple version, you're getting approximately 2x speedup, and you have 2 cores!

Comment: Sorry, I confused with and without OpenMP. But my question is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function `clock()` measures processor time consumed by whole process, so printed time shows sum of time consumed by all threads. If you want to see wall-time (real time elapsed from the begin to the end), use e.g. [times()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/times.html) function on the POSIX system

Comment: One problem is that you are using clock() to measure the time. The man page for clock says "the clock() function returns an approximation of processor time used by the program". Processor time for a parallel run will usually be larger than the serial run. You want to measure wall clock time. OpenMP provides a function to do this. See omp_get_wtime() in the OpenMP spec for information.

Comment: Thank you so much! I try omp_get_wtime() and show that OpenMP program works faster. Now I have maximum speedup with 32 threads.

Comment: @Mikhail: 32 threads on a 2-core machine?  Really?  That makes little sense.  You are either compute-bound or memory-bound, and in your code, having more threads than there are cores won't improve matters.  So I'm surprised.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is so simple that you're probably being limited by memory bandwidth.  I rarely get any speedups until the work is much more than the time it takes to get the data to and from the work.  Plus a reduction has extra work in merging all the sub results.